# Tagged equation on the same line as a list marker?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, lists, tags

How can I have a tagged equation on the same line as a list marker?

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \[\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c) = \gcd(a,\gcd(b,c)) \tag{associativity}\]
\end{enumerate}
```

I tried different environments but they either produce a "line feed" (like the above) or don't allow `\tag` inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the equation centered using `\hfill`s. The closing `\mbox` ensures the "tag" is set in text mode, although it's not technically necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \[\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c) = \gcd(a,\gcd(b,c)) \tag{associativity}\]
  
  \item \hfill
  $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c) = \gcd(a,\gcd(b,c))$\hfill
  \mbox{(associativity)}%
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

In the above case, setting a `\label` will reference the `enumerate`'s `\item`, rather than the set "tag". However, it would be possible to update that reference, if needed.